# Process never end when I run a command inside a container using Python

Tags: python-3.x, docker, subprocess, logstash

with a python script Im running logstash via command inside a docker container, the normal behavior (with logstash installed in the server) is that after the pipeline get the data that pipeline shuts down, but the process never ends.

```
logstash=subprocess.call(["docker","exec", "-it", "logstash-docker_logstash_1", "/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash","-f", "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/site-canvas.conf","--path.data","/usr/share/logstash/config/min-data/"])
```

Im using docker top to see the running processes inside the container

what can I do to ensure that the process end when finish getting the data?

This is my pipeline

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver:/db-ip:1433;databasename=omi"
        jdbc_user => "my-user"
        jdbc_password => "my-pass"

        statement => "SELECT
                    TIME_CREATED,DESCRIPTION as problem, SEVERITY as severity_mame, NODEHINTS_DNSNAME as source,CATEGORY
                    FROM [omi1062event].[dbo].[ALL_EVENTS]
                    WHERE  STATE = 'OPEN'
                    AND NODEHINTS_DNSNAME LIKE 'mju%'
                    AND TIME_CREATED >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
                    ORDER BY TIME_CREATED ASC
                    "
        jdbc_default_timezone => "UTC"
    }
}

filter {
        date {
            match => [ "time_created", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" ]
            timezone => "Chile/Continental"
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "my-ip:9200"
        index => "canvas"
        user => "my-user"
        password => "my-pass"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your logstash pipeline?

Comment: Hi, I added my pipeline

Comment: Are you trying to run a second copy of Logstash inside an existing Logstash container?  I believe `logstash` is a long-running process that will continuously scan the sources you give and forwards log messages on; do you expect it to exit?

Comment: yes, if you not provide a cron for the pipeline to consult the DB, it will exit, I do this in the logstash installed in the physical server